# Define Python script arguments in a separate file

Tags: python, python-import

I have a python script with many arguments. I'd like to be able call this script by passing arguments directly from command line but also by predefining these arguments in another python file and call that instead.

So my main python `run.py` file looks like this:

```py
def main():
    ....

def parse_arguments():
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':

  config = parse_arguments()
  main(config)
```

And I can have a `experiment.py` in the same directory that does:

```py
from run import main

config = ...

main(config)
```

This works fine if I put `experiment.py` is in root but I have quite a few of these files so I prefer to put them in a separate `experiments` folder and have a structure like:

```
package
    experiments
        experiment1.py
        experiment2.py
        experiment3.py
        ...
        experiment100.py

    run.py
```

I obviously can't do `python experiments/experiment1.py` because relative importing won't work. What's the elegant way to deal with this without changing the hierarchy of my existing files too much?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how these experiments relate to the run.py file here.

Comment: Use tests and/or packages (if you make the folders a real packages, you will be able to use relative importing). You can also do `sys.path.append` to append a path that is not a package or even not in your project's location to PATH.

Comment: @AKX They basically call `main()` from `run.py` with different set of arguments. I just don't want to define args in the command line because I've got so many

Comment: Have you tried using relative import and running `python -m experiments.experiment1` from the package directory?

Comment: I just tried the `-m` option but I'm still seeing `__main__` when I print `__name__` in `experiments.experiment1` which means relative importing doesn't work.